# Python delete lines of text line #1 till regex

Tags: python, regex

I have an issue that I can't seem to find a solution within python.

From command line I can do this by:
sed '1,/COMMANDS/d' /var/tmp/newFile

This delete everything from line #1 till regex "COMMANDS".  Simple

But I can't do the same with Python that I can find.
The re.sub and multiline doesn't seem to work.

So I have a question how can I do this in a pythonic way?  I really rather not run sed from within python unless I have to.

Comment: my guess is that `sed` works on a character stream (e.g. in-place) while `re.sub` works on strings (which are immutable therefore not in-place). If you include some code so we know where you went wrong, it's probably easily solved.

Comment: an example would be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) with `inplace=True` to actually change the original file setting a flag when you find the match and removing lines until you do:

```
import fileinput
import re
found = False
for line in fileinput.input("your_file",inplace=True):
    if re.match("pattern",line):
        found = True
    if found:
        print(line,end="") # print line, python2
    else:
        print(end="") # print, python2
```

If there is nothing too complex about the pattern `if "pattern" in line` may also work.

Comment: I always forget about `fileinput`.

Comment: @AdamSmith,  I think a lot of people do including myself sometimes, it is ideal when you want to modify a file  in place.

Comment: this almost worked perfectly! Thank you!
The issue is that I am using python2.7 so "end" doesn't work.

I edited it this way:
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function

import fileinput
import re

found = False
for line in fileinput.input("/var/tmp/mapr_nagios.cfg",inplace=True):
    if re.match("^.*COMMANDS .*$",line):
        found = True
    if found:
        #print (line, end=" ") # print line, python2
 print(line, end='') 
    else:
        print(end='')# print, python2

Works great!

Answer (score 0):

Set a flag false.

Iterate over each line. 
For each line,
1) When you match your pattern, set a flag.
2) If the flag is currently set set, print the line.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty:

```
import re

regex = re.compile('(^|\n)(pattern)(\n|$)')

with open('file.txt') as f:
    entire_file = f.read()

with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    print(regex.split(entire_file)[0], end='', file=f)
```

Although it's probably not a good idea to run a regex over entire file unless you have to (e.g. if your pattern spans multiple lines).